# Django-Admin Panel Wont Show Records that are inserted throw phpmyadmin?

Tags: python, mysql, django, phpmyadmin, django-admin

I have a django admin panel , and this django admin panel is connected to mysql and wamp .

My problem is when i insert some records in database using phpmyadmin , django-admin panel wont show records , and just show numbers of them .

What this problem is for ?

Here is My Model in Django :

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    objects = jmodels.jManager()
    product = models.ForeignKey('PartoProducts', models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_phone = models.ForeignKey('PartoUsers', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_phone')
    order_date = jmodels.jDateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    count = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.title
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'orders'
        verbose_name_plural = "Orders"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s------- (%s)' % (self.user_phone,self.status)
```

and This is My Admin.py for this model :

```
class OrdersResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta : 
        model = Orders
        fields = ('product__title','product__realprice','user_phone__name','user_phone__family','user_phone__city','user_phone__address','user_phone__nationalcode')
@admin.register(Orders)
class OrdersAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('product','user_phone','price')
    list_filter = ('product','user_phone','price')
    search_fields = ('product','user_phone','price')
    resource_class = OrdersResource
```

Why django wont show any records that are inserted throw phpmyadmin ?

I searched alot but not found anything .

Any Suggestion will be helpfull .

Thanks to this great community .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution !!!

I Just need to change my model field :

From This :

```
user_phone = models.ForeignKey('PartoUsers', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_phone')
```

To This :

```
 user_phone = models.ForeignKey('PartoUsers',models.DO_NOTHING,db_column='user_phone',to_field='phone')
```

And Yes , This is solved my problem .